# std::thread constructor Is there a difference between passing a pointer and passing by ref?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, pass-by-reference, member-functions

When creating a thread that calls a member function, is there a difference between passing a pointer to the current class or passing a reference?

From the example below, does method1 behave the same as method2? Are there any differences?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};
    void memberFunction1()
    {
        //method 1
        std::thread theThread(&MyClass::memberFunction2, this, argumentToMemberFunction2)

        //method 2
        std::thread theThread(&MyClass::memberFunction2, std::ref(*this), argumentToMemberFunction2)
    }
    void memberFunction2(const double& someDouble){};
}
```

Comment: Assuming it compiles, there shouldn't be. References are syntactic sugar for pointers. Doesn't mean it couldn't screw up the compiler though, as it's syntactically dubious to pass the `std::ref` `reference_wrapper` when the call is performed (internally) with `this` as a pointer as the first object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no differences, but note that using a reference wrapper has only become possible with the acceptance of [LWG 2219](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2219) as a defect report at the Oct 2015 WG21 meeting.*

Using `std::ref` may help in cases where you have a named object instance rather than `this`, since `this` is quite easy to spell. But consider the following situation, in which you'd like to stay nicely const-correct:

```
A a;
std::thread(&A::foo, std::cref(a), 1, 2);
```

This may be easier to read than:

```
std::thread(&A::foo, &(const_cast<const A&>(a)), 1, 2);
std::thread(&A::foo, &as_const(a), 1, 2);
std::thread(&A::foo, const_cast<const A*>(&a), 1, 2);
```

<sub>*) Vendors that keep distinct language dialects around, like GCC's and Clang with the `-std` flag), will typically consider defects to apply to all dialects and "fix" the implementations. Defects are things that "were always meant to be the way we say now".</sub>

Comment: The `std::ref` example shouldn't even compile, *INVOKE* doesn't have special handling for `reference_wrapper` - https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2219

Comment: Glad you undeleted :) Looks like this was added very recently to libstdc++ - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59768

Comment: It is indeed in the working draft now, just looked at N4567 and its definition of *INVOKE* includes handling `reference_wrapper`

Comment: @Praetorian: Forget it, it does apply. I was just confused. Yes, the LWG issue changes the interpretation from `(*t1).*f` to `t1.get().*f` when `t1` is a reference wrapper, which finally makes this work. This has been accepted as a defect report, so I suppose implementers will patch this even into previous language dialects (like GCC's `c++11` and `c++14`).

Comment: @Praetorian: Looks like someone needs to update the documentation for [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

Comment: Maybe TC or Cubbi will come across this answer and do it :) The "possible implementation" needs some unwrapping code added to it also.